# TDictionary.ContainsKey returning false, even though the key exists

Tags: delphi, generics, dictionary, delphi-xe2

The problem I'm facing now has totally made me feel like I don't understand programming at all. I have a `TDictionary` object which consists of pairs of `TDate => TEvent (custom class)`. The object is used in a class which is shared by two separate applications (they don't communicate). In one application, the following works correctly:

```
  //  Get recipes from the very event.
  Tmp := FCalendar.ContainsKey(D);
  if (Tmp) then
  begin
    E := FCalendar[D];
    CopyRecipes(E);
  end;
```

On the other hand, the same piece of code doesn't work in the other application ! How is that possible? I have attached a screenshot of what is happening in the debugger: [image]

As you can see, the key is present in the dictionary, and yet `ContainsKey()` returns `FALSE`.

What is causing this?

Regards,
Patryk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that `TDate` is actually just a `TDateTime`. That means it is a double precision value holding number of days since the Delphi epoch. The IDE debug hints for a `TDate` show just the date part and omit the time part. You are comparing for equality and so two values that are in the same day, but have different time components will not be equal. Here's a screenshot to illustrate:

[image]

Solve the problem by using [`DateOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.DateOf) to remove the time part of the date time. You will have to use `DateOf` whenever you receive a date value, and clearly before you add to the dictionary.

Comment: How can you explain that it works in one application and not in the other?

Comment: Take a look at `D` and `Key` cast as `TDateTime` and you will see the difference. As to the question in that comment, you are asking a bit much aren't you?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't mean offence. You are right, that was the case. Using `DateOf()` solves the problem. Thanks, David!

Comment: No offence taken. I just couldn't answer questions about your apps. Anyway, good that you are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

possibly in D not 2011-11-11
possibly D:=2011-11-11 00-00-00